# Find The Parity Outlier - Solution works for some tests but not all - any idea why?

Tags: javascript

So the task is as follows:

You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

Examples
[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
Should return: 11 (the only odd number)

[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
Should return: 160 (the only even number)

My solution is as follows:

```js
function findOutlier(integers) {
  const arr = integers.map(mov => mov % 2);
  const oddOrEven = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
  if (oddOrEven === 1) {
    let indexOdd = arr.findIndex(mov => mov === 1);
    return integers[indexOdd]
  } else {
    let indexEven = arr.findIndex(mov => mov === 0)
    return integers[indexEven]
  }
}

console.log(findOutlier([2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36])); // 11
console.log(findOutlier([160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21])); // 160
```

Can anyone see why this is returning as working for some tests but not all?

Comment: Please add tests for which the code is not working.

Comment: You could have a negative odd number in an array of evens, in that case oddOrEven === -1